# Loss is growing between epochs in simple model

Tags: python, curve-fitting, stochastic-gradient-descent

I am new to ML and trying to write a very simple model that can predict the future of a function given the past. That is to say, I define a simple cubic function (y = x^3 + x^2 + x) and apply it to a domain of 100 points from x = -10 to x = 10. I would like to use the first 80 points -- `params = y[:80]` -- to train some weights using SGD -- `weights = np.random.normal((20,80))`. The reason I decided to choose this shape for my weights is that `weights @ params` will return an array with only 20 items, which are compared with `trgts = y[80:]` using the `torch.nn.MSELoss` function.

When I run my code, which I will post in full below, my loss function diverges rather than converging. I would like to know why this is.

```
import numpy as np
import torch

x = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
y = x**3 + x**2 + x

loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction = 'sum')

def get_trgts(i): return torch.tensor(y[i:])
def get_weights(i,o): return torch.tensor(np.random.normal(0,3,(o,i))).requires_grad_()
def get_params(i): return torch.tensor(y[:i])

weights = get_weights(80,20)
trgts = get_trgts(80)
params = get_params(80)
bias = get_weights(1,1)
    
lr = 1e-6
def apply_step(weights, bias, prn = True):
    preds = weights@params + bias
    loss = loss_fn(preds,trgts)
    loss.backward()
    with torch.no_grad():
        weights -= weights.grad * lr
        bias -= bias.grad * lr
        weights.grad.zero_()
        bias.grad.zero_()
    if prn: print(loss.item())
    return preds

for i in range(10): apply_step(weights, bias)
```

The printed output in one case is:

```
1305310646.9058952
184198069792.42996
25992991779912.277
3667984265155172.0
5.176052331083886e+17
7.304152852734643e+19
1.0307208174021644e+22
1.4544950315880012e+24
2.0525012798773587e+26
2.8963739390011883e+28
```

Which is evidently diverging.

P.S. I understand that in its current form, the model is useless, I'm simply using it to learn the principles.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the error. Changing the learning rate to `lr = 1e-7` will cause the loss to converge rather than diverge! Thanks to anyone who spent time considering my question.